# c＃配列を利用してCSVファイルの操作

Tags: c#, csv, array, datagridview

開発環境　visual studio2017
言語　C#

流れ
◯①csvファイルを読み込む（カラム数１０件、データ数１０件）
×②読み込んだファイルのデータを使い異なるレイアウトのcsvファイルを作成する（カラム数7件、データ数５件）＝残り2点は読み込み時に存在しない列なので空（””）にする
読み込みサンプル

```
カラム1,カラム2,カラム3,カラム4,カラム5,カラム6,カラム7,カラム8,カラム9,カラム10
１,２,３,４,５,６,７,８,９,１０
```

変更後
（元CSVの列の前後は変わらず、間に新規のものが入るか、途中や後ろの列が削られるだけはなく完全にバラバラになります。）

```
からむ1,カラムA,からむ2,からむ3,カラムB,からむ4,からむ5
”1”,””,”2”,”3”,””,”4”,”5”
```

⬆️サンプルのレイアウトを利用して列にデータを投入するイメージです。
カタカナと平仮名の違い＝データは同じだが、列名が異なる事を表しています
　　☝️店舗名＝ショップ名など該当するデータは同じだが表記が異なる事なので値は変わりません。
　質問内容は②と③のレイアウトを変更する箇所になります。
考え方がよく分からなかったのですが、読み込むファイルの列数とレイアウト変更後の列数は変動することは無いので不変ではなく一回設定したら常に変更の列順は固定になる想定なので
一括でファイル読み込みしてから列の削除を行い、新規の列を作り追加した後に全体の列の順番を調整の手順でコードを作成するという考えですか？
①読み込み

```
private DataTable ReadCSV(string fp)
{
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(fp,encoding);//一括でファイル読み込み

    if(lines.Length>0)
    {
        foreach(string strWorld in strHeader)
        {    
            dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(strWorld));
        }

        for(int row=1;row<lines.Length;row++)
        {
            string[] word = lines[row].Split(',');
            DataRow dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            int columindex = 0;

            foreach(string strWorld in strHeader)
            {
                dataRow[strWorld] = word[columindex++];
            }      
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);      
        }
    }
    return dataTable;
}
```

Comment: ちなみにCSVの`カラム２`の`２`が全角なのは、そういう仕様ですか、それとも転記ミスで実は半角の`2`ですか？

Comment: @kunif  ちなみにCSVのカラム２の２が全角なのは、そういう仕様ですか、それとも転記ミスで実は半角の2ですか？ ＝＞ ご指摘ありがとうございます。ミスになります、、修正致しました。

Comment: カラムは並び替えか減らす方向だと思っていましたが、並び替えかつ増やすのなら、その仕組みはどうなっているのでしょうか？ 何か計算で？あるいは複数のCSVの結合とか？

Comment: @kunif    読みこむcsvファイルA（仮列名：名前、メール、電話、住所、年齢）だとしてレイアウト変更後のcsvファイルB（仮列名：コード、名前、住所、性別）のような列になっている状況で読み込むデータの列数は３０、変更後の列数は２０で減ってはいるのですが、全て使っているわけではなくて読み込んだファイルから中必要なデータだけ持ってきて該当する箇所にいれる事を想定しています

Comment: なので変更後カラムデータはあるが該当するデータが無い物も存在します(カラム１カラム２カラム３)あるがデータは（"",col2,col3）のように空欄（""）もあります。説明が下手で申し訳ございません

Comment: コメントではあまり詳しい記述は出来ないので質問記事を変更点が分かるように編集してください。例えば`コード`のような新しい項目はいくつあって、それの値はどうやって決められるのでしょう？

Comment: @kunif  編集の方致しました。何度も聞いてしまいすみません

Comment: 元CSVの列の前後は変わらず、間に新規のものが入るか、途中や後ろの列が削られるだけでしょうか？ カラム名のカタカナひらがなとか、各セルの値とか、何か法則があって変わったり値が新たに決まるものは何か、といった情報も追記してください。

Comment: 元csvの列番号を取得して新しい列の番号を指定できたらなと考えております。前後前後が変わらずや新しい物が間に新規に入るなどの制約では無いです。質問の方にも追記致しました。ご返答本当にありがとうございます。@kunif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**質問の詳細化に合わせて全面改訂：**

DataTableの各行のデータ追加は、基本的には以下の記事が参考になるでしょう。
[DataTableの実践的な使い方](https://qiita.com/tizonaColada_99/items/9212d35722af3bd5bc9f#datatable%E3%81%AE%E5%AE%9F%E8%B7%B5%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AA%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9)

CSVデータファイルを読み取って通知された作業用のDataTableを基に`foreach`でループすれば良いでしょう。
とりあえず動作確認していない概念的なものですが、以下になります。
あるいは、ReadCSV()を汎用的に作らずに、以下を応用して専用の処理を作ることもできるでしょう。

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("ResultTable"); // 結果用テーブル作成
table.Columns.Add("からむ1", typeof(String));
table.Columns.Add("カラムA", typeof(String));
table.Columns.Add("からむ2", typeof(String));
table.Columns.Add("からむ3", typeof(String));
table.Columns.Add("カラムB", typeof(String));
table.Columns.Add("からむ4", typeof(String));
table.Columns.Add("からむ5", typeof(String));

DataTable csvtable = ReadCSV('CSVデータファイルパス'); // CSVデータ取得

foreach(DataRow csvrow in csvtable) // コピー処理
{
    DataRow dtrow = table.NewRow();
    
    dtrow["からむ1"] = csvrow["カラム1"];
    dtrow["カラムA"] = "";
    dtrow["からむ2"] = csvrow["カラム2"];
    dtrow["からむ3"] = csvrow["カラム3"];
    dtrow["カラムB"] = "";
    dtrow["からむ4"] = csvrow["カラム4"];
    dtrow["からむ5"] = csvrow["カラム5"];
    // 入れるデータの無いカラムは特に空文字列を入れなくても良いかも？
    
    table.Rows.Add(dtrow);
}
```

DataGridViewへの反映や結果のCSVファイルへの出力は別途行ってください。

p.s.
この回答へのコメントも意味が無いものになるので消しておいてください。